# Android Studio - searching bluetooth devices

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

I would like to write an app that can search bluetooth devices, add founded devices to ListView, connect with one of this devices and send some text. But now I am not able to search devices. When I was overlooking logs I noticed that sometimes the searching works. But even if it worked nothing was added to the ListView.

It can be important - I have devices with Android 4.2 and 5.1.
Could anybody help me find mistakes in my code?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnConnect;
    Button btnSend;
    ListView lvDeviceList;
    TextView tvOutgoingMessage;
    TextView tvIncomingMessage;

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    public ArrayList<String> BTDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    public ListAdapter deviceListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "ONCREATE");
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        lvDeviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.devicesList);
        tvOutgoingMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outgoingMessage);
        tvIncomingMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.incommingMessage);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                 if (checkIfEnable()) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "ONCREATE - IF");
                     Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                     discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
                     startActivity(discoverableIntent);

                     discoverDevices();


                     connect();
                 }

            }
        });
    }

    public boolean checkIfEnable() {
        boolean existance = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "CHECK IF ENABLE");
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IN 1ST IF");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device doesn't support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            existance = false;
        }
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null && !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IN 2ND IF");
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }

        return existance;
    }

    private void discoverDevices() {

        Log.d(TAG, "DISCOVER DEVICES");
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);



        // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ON RECEIVE");
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
                    // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                    // object and its info from the Intent.
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    String deviceName = device.getName();
                    String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                    BTDevices.add(deviceName);
                    lvDeviceList.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                }
            }
        };



    }

    private void connect() {
        Log.d(TAG, "CONNECT");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't call `lvDeviceList.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter)` on each device found. Move this line to `onCreate()`. The second - you should pass `BTDevices` to your adapter(this part is important and it's missing in your code) and on each `BTDevices.add(deviceName)` you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: Thanks, the ListView works, but I still have a problem with searching devices. It works only in one situation. I must have bluetooth turned off. When I click on a button search for the first time bluetooth is turning on, but no devices apear in ListView. After second clik, my phone "discovers" many times the same device. After third and next clik the phone discover no devices.

Comment: I found the solution. Adding _cancelDiscovery()_ helped me.